# Greater/Less Than Comparison in Python

Tags: python, comparison, standards

When implementing the rich comparison methods in a class, what should be returned when comparing two different class types? From the documentation it says

> Instances of a class cannot be ordered with respect to other instances of the same class, or other types of object, unless the class defines either enough of the rich comparison methods (`__lt__()`, `__le__()`, `__gt__()`, and `__ge__()`) or the `__cmp__()` method.

However, I can't find anywhere in the documentation where it mentions the standard return type for comparison between two different classes. I'd like to know the standard for both `Python 2` and `Python 3`.

Answer (score 1):

[`__cmp__`](https://docs.python.org/2.7/reference/datamodel.html#object.__cmp__) ([Python 2.x only](https://docs.python.org/3.0/whatsnew/3.0.html#ordering-comparisons)) should return negative for `self < other`, zero for `self == other` and positive for `self > other`.

[The others](https://docs.python.org/2.7/reference/datamodel.html#object.__le__) ("rich comparison methods", 2.x and 3.x) should return appropriate booleans, e.g. `__lt__(self, other)` should return `True` when `self < other`, `False` otherwise.

Comment: In 2.x and 3.x, except that 3.x doesn't use `__cmp__`. See e.g. https://docs.python.org/3.4/reference/datamodel.html#object.__lt__