# About custom heap in python

Tags: python, heap

I looked at previous posts of creating custom heaps by defining classes and `__lt__` functions.
Here is what I did:

```
import heapq

class MyObjects:
    def __init__(self, val0, val1):
        self.val0 = val0
        self.val1 = val1
                
    def __repr__(self):
        return "[{},{}]".format(self.val0, self.val1)
                
    def __lt__(self, other):
        return self.val1 - other.val1
        
heap = []
heapq.heapify(heap)

intervals = [4, 9], [4, 17], [9, 10]
for interval in intervals:
    heapq.heappush(heap, MyObjects(interval[0], interval[1]))
    print(heap[0])
```

The elements I put in this heap are two value lists and I hope to compare the second values and have list of the smallest second value on top of the heap.

I expect during the for loop the first time list is [4,9], the second time is [4,9], the third time is [4,9].

But the result is first time the top is [4,9], second time is [4,17], third time is [9,10].

It seems the heap didn't put the list with the smallest second value on the top.

Comment: Why does your `__lt__` method subtract the two values? Use `return self.val1 < other.val1` instead. Negative numbers are _truthy_ in Python

Comment: [This appears to answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23186055/greater-less-than-comparison-in-python) your question. `__lt__` should return a boolean.

Comment: Thank you! Yes, after I changed lt method to "self.val1<other.val1" the result is correct now. I used to use java and in java compare() method it returns an int value.